# WiFi suddenly slows down/stops working after an hour or so

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I'm running Windows 7 (64-bit) SP1 and using a TP-LINK N600 PCI Express adapter (Model No. TL-WDN3800) for WiFi. I'm using the 21/02/2012 (version 9.2.0.489) driver from [TP-LINK](http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/?model=TL-WDN3800&version=V1).

When I turn my computer on the WiFi connects fine and shows 4 or 5 bars out of 5 with a signal strength of "Excellent" and reports a wireless speed of 72.2Mbps. After an hour or so the Internet connection will either stop or grind to a halt for no apparent reason. Disabling and enabling the WiFi adapter restores the WiFi to its previous speed for another hour or so then slow down again.

**This is highly unlikely to be an issue with the wireless reception or wireless router** as it works fine for the first hour or so, and other wireless devices in the same location do not experience the same problem.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue, or to troubleshoot it further?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest firmware on both wireless router and the wireless adapter.

Try to disable, one at a time, various router features on the wireless router, like

- if there are only wireless N devices, disable B/G
- restrict channel width to 20MHz instead of 20/40
- change the wireless channel; a wifi survery helps to find the "least noisy" one

I had similar issues with a first-gen macbook air (wireless stopped working, other newer devices were fine), and at some point I found a wireless setup on the router that helped.

Comment: The mode is on N, it doesn't support the higher frequency band so that's not an issue, and I already did a survey and it is on a channel without much interference. Again, it's highly unlikely to be a wireless reception problem because the reception is **fine** and I get a decent speed for the first hour or so.

Comment: I though any N router had the 20/40Mhz setting, since my old 150N/2.4GHz single band does. I understant it is not bad signal, but frequent interferences leading to retransmissions may expose bugs in wireless drivers

Comment: Although it doesn't make too much sense, changing the channel from 1 to 12 does seem to have improved things to some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your ISP is limiting the amount of data you can use, in a certain timeframe. e.g they are trying to prevent youfrom using more than 1GB per hour/session whatever .... it may help if you call up your ISP see if your plan allows you to use so much data for an unlimited session and if not upgrade your plan otherwise log into manual configuration of your router ... in various countries and ISP's their is a different method to do so
the most common is to type in your IP address to the address bar ( google - what is my ip it will give yoy a number something like 12.345.567.890 type this into the ADDRESS BAR (the bit currently showing : [WiFi suddenly slows down/stops working after an hour or so](https://superuser.com/questions/874878/wifi-suddenly-slows-down-stops-working-after-an-hour-or-so) )  and type in your username and password (should have been provided to you when you bought your internet connection or wil be written on the back of your router) and check the settings there ... to see if something is limiting your data usage

Comment: It's not an ISP issue. As I said in the question, I don't experience the issue on any other devices on the same connection at all. There's nothing limiting my data usage.

Comment: My Apologies, a similair thing happened to me and this is how I tried to solve it ... since it was infrequent I just didnt bother and would disconnect and recconect whenever it became a problem